# Align vertically different paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I am working with this website created with Drupal www.crincon.com. 
The section under the slides, contains several blocks with nested divs elements and a link at the end.

[Block caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvImi.png)

What I would like to do is that the links "Read More" (with button aspect) will be all at the same height, with the same vertical alignment for all the blocks, to be displayed at the same level.

The HTML for all the blocks looks like this:

```html
<div class="column one">
<div class="region region-top-first">
  <div id="block-block-7" class="block block-block">

      
  <div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the market of Russia, CIS and Baltic States</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
  
</div> <!-- /.block -->
</div>
 <!-- /.region -->
</div>
```

I have tried many different options looking at some responses here (like relative-absolute position), but with no success.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your **CSS** too..

Comment: Provide jsfiddle url.

Comment: you can use position to align things in same place, better you post the exact html and css, so that someone can help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

position the read more button like below code. I add a class .readmore to the button.

```
.readmore {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 }
.content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The key was about positioning the button correctly and add these classes.

Comment: No problem. Yeah position is key here for align elements.

Answer (score 1):

You may use flex to make this easy :

```css
.block {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap
}
.content {
  text-align:center;
  padding:1em;
  background:#0194CA;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 1px,inset 0 0 40px white;
  width:15%;
  min-width:150px;
/* what does the thing you want , stands here below , but parent has to be a wrapping flex element : */
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div id="block-block-7" class="block block-block">
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the market of Russia, </h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the market of Russia, CIS and Baltic States</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization Baltic States</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the market of Russia, CIS and Baltic States</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the market of Russia, CIS and Baltic States</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <p><i class="fa fa-flag fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h2>Localization to the market of Russia, CIS and Baltic States</h2>
    <p><a href="en/services/localization">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help you somehow.

```
#top-area a {
    color: #ECF9FD;
    border: 1px solid #92DAF5;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
}
```